# Why am I able to export private keys using my seedless online Electrum wallet?

Tags: wallet, electrum

Why am I able to export private keys using my seedless online Electrum wallet?

I thought this wallet is not meant to be able to expose any of my Bitcoin, but yet it has the option to export private keys? I have not gone to the point of actually exporting them because I'm scared it will compromise me somehow since I can't even set a password on seedless Electrum, so perhaps it is just a redundant option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a gui bug; the menu did not really export private keys.

fixed here: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/commit/3fc7d0ef9e34465a47017ffa1f567d829aa0f2a2